# Can I use a double pole breaker in a slot that allows tandem breakers?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, circuit

I have a Siemens 200 Amp 30 spaces/40 circuit load center that allows me to use tandem breakers. I am not interested in using them, but I'd like to add one 45 Amp double pole circuit breaker.

Would be possible to have the 45A double pole circuit breaker installed in a space where tandem breakers are designed to be? Is it OK and legal?

This is my electrical panel and you can see on the bottom the tandem designated spots looking to the tabs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you edit to post a clear picture of the panel labeling?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, I just added the panel label. Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, (all, AFAIK) panels that take tandems will happily take regular breakers in the same spots, and a double pole is simply two regular breakers, as far as the bus is concerned.

Comment: I just added the panel label. Thanks

Comment: My old GE panel relies on thin 1/2" 1-pole breakers to get enough circuits. GE also makes thin 2-pole breakers 1" total. The result is that I once tried to put in a thin 2-pole breaker (1" total) into a single 1" slot. It looks like it would fit, but will not snap in. The thin 2-pole must be inserted astride two 1" slots so it takes 1/2" from each slot. Only in this way could it work because the two halves must be connected to different legs. I tried hard to force it into the single slot but I did stop and retreat to think about it before I damaged anything.

Comment: My point is that for this OP's panel the slots at the bottom allow half height breakers to be installed. A half height 2-pole breaker cannot be put iinto two half height slots that are on the same leg. Like my GE panel I am sure the half height slots have a mechanical excluder which prevents the half height 2-pole breaker from snapping into one slot in which both bus tabs are on the same leg.

Comment: This is **not** the special case of GE's unique approach. This panel does not take "half-height breakers" it takes tandems (two breakers, immutably wedded at the factory, in one body of normal size)(but only in those spots) and the OP has explicitly stated they are not interested in using tandems at all.